# Convert svn passwd file to htpasswd

Tags: svn, apache-2.2

I would like to import the usernames and passwords in the `svn/conf/passwd` file into apache's `htpasswd` format. Is there any utility that can help me?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a direct utility, but you can probably rig one up with sed and [htpasswd](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/htpasswd.html), e.g.

```
sed -ne "s/\(.*[^ ]\) *\= *\([^ ].*\)/htpasswd -b password_file \"\1\" \"\2\"/p"
    < svn/conf/passwd > out.sh
```

to build a script that'll hopefully generate the file for you. Untested, sorry - don't have apache to hand. You'll need to create the password file first.

Comment: Thanks this would really help me in the future! However, for now I just managed to do it by hand! :)